# How to make a WPF ListView no taller than its contents but fit to the window with other controls?

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls, autoresize, docking

I'm trying to arrange a WPF UI as follows:

[image: Mock up]

1. At top of the window are some controls of self-determining height (effectively docked to the top of the window, but as tall as they want to be).
2. Beneath those controls is a ListView. The ListView may contain a variable number of items each of varying height. **The problem:** The ListView mustn't be taller than it needs to be. If all the items in the list view will easily fit into the window, I want the ListView to be *exactly the height to show all its items* (so the window looks like a web page's flowing layout with blank space at the bottom). On the other hand if all ListView items won't fit into the window, I want *the whole UI to fit to the window* (as if number 3
   below was docked to the bottom of the window, and the ListView was filling the available space). This all has to adjust dynamically as the user resizes the window and/or presses buttons which change the list view's contents.
3. Beneath the ListView are some more controls of self-determining height. These must appear directly under the ListView at all times, with no gap. In particular they mustn't just dock to the bottom of the window if they'll fit directly under the ListView.

Solutions would be very welcome; I've fiddled for some time and managed to get things working **except** the controls beneath the ListView, by using an outer DockPanel in the window with the first controls docked to the top, and the ListView filling the remaining space but set to VerticalAlignment="Top".

A pure XAML solution would be ideal, but I don't mind code behind if it's unavoidable. Bonus points for a solution which allows multiple such arrangements to be stacked vertically :) Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Content="hello" />
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" >
    <ListView >
            <ListBoxItem Content="hi" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="hi" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="hi" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="hi" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="hi" />
            <!-- Some Items -->
    </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Content="hello" Grid.Row="2" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: So simple! And exactly what I want. That VerticalAlignment="Top" on the Grid seems to be the key, really didn't occur to me at all but makes perfect sense. (Edit: I don't need the ScrollViewer, the ListView scrolls itself if required and fits nicely regardless.) Thanks so much.

Comment: You are losing on virtualization here though.

Comment: If you remove the scollviewer, scrolling works better. Listview has a scrollviewer built in. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932720/listview-inside-of-scrollviewer-prevents-scrollviewer-scroll

Answer (score 1):

Use Grid with three rows and set the height of all three to Auto so that they will size to content.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationUnleashed.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationUnleashed"
        Title="Window1" >
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Margin="10">These are top controls</Button>
            <Label Margin="10">These are top controls</Label>
            <TextBox Margin="10">These are top controls</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <TreeView Margin="10" Grid.Row="1">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1" >
                <TreeViewItem Header=" Sub Item 1" />
                <TreeViewItem Header=" Sub Item 2" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Sub Item 3" />
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item 2" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item 3" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item 4" />
        </TreeView>

        <StackPanel Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Margin="10">These are bottom controls</Button>
            <Label Margin="10">These are bottom controls</Label>
            <TextBox Margin="10">These are bottom controls</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Sadly that won't size the list box as I want it (only as big as required, but smaller to fit to window if required). It ends up with the ListBox being as large as it'd like to be, which causes it to have no scroll bars, plus the bottom self-sizing controls aren't visible.

Comment: I was some seconds late in posting the code, I had also set the VerticalALignment to Top.

Comment: +1 for that key setting in that case, thanks very much for answering.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the size, too. And the answer was really to set the *Height* Property of my Grid Rows. I have the following setup:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding AuditEntries}"
                         Margin="1 0 1 1" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

So what really solved my problem was to set the *Height* property of the first row definition (that contains my *ListBox*):

```
<RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
```

What jolly fun...

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it enough to just put the listview and the bottom controls into their own stackpanel?

Comment: I thought so too, but either it doesn't work or my execution sucks - it works great when the whole ListView plus other controls fit in the window, but won't make the ListView smaller if it has to. I also toyed with grids, but to no avail so far.