# Listview inside of scrollviewer prevents scrollviewer scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollviewer

I have a scrollviewer with a couple listboxes in it. The problem is if a user uses the middle mouse roller to scroll the scrollviewer while their mouse is over a listview. The listview scrolls its internal scrollviewer to the bottom and then continues to capture the mouse, preventing the containing scrollviewer from scrolling.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: I have the same problem. There's a discussion here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/wpf/thread/b440b2cb-26e0-4115-9858-5679c4e45e0a I'll let you know if I resolve the problem.

Answer (score 69):

That happens because the `ListView`'s (`ListBox`'s, actually) content template wraps its items with a `ScrollViewer` by itself.

The simplest way is to disable it by dropping your own `Template` for the inside `ListView`, one that doesn't create a `ScrollViewer`:

```
    <ListView>
      <ListView.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
          <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </ListView.Template>
      ...
    </ListView>
```

BTW the same happens if you have a ListView inside a ListView (this was my case).

Comment: This solution worked nicely for me and it is easy to implement. I tried other suggested solutions, but only this worked for me (ListViewer inside a ScrollViewer)

Comment: I was looking for exactly this. Been a long time windows 10 dev and this issue caught me by surprise in WPF. Thanks +1 :)

Comment: Haha thanks! I haven't touched any C# since 2013, happy to see that this answer is still relevant!

Comment: Not a solution because this code removes the ListView Header. -1

Answer (score 8):

IMO, the best way to handle this scenario is to create a custom control :

```
     class MyScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
     {
         protected override void OnPreviewMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
         {
            base.OnPreviewMouseWheel(e);
            if (!e.Handled)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                this.RaiseEvent(new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta)
                {
                    RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent,
                    Source = this
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is the best, because other answers, will remove the header, and to solve this you will need to implement the ScrollViewer from the ground see [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719006/wpf-listview-custom-scrollviewer-causes-column-header-to-disappear) 

[help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784207/custom-wpf-listview-with-style-using-datatemplate-how-do-i-add-headers)

Answer (score 6):

Did you try disabling the `ListView's` `ScrollBars`?

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
```

Comment: I can't do that because the listviews may have more items than are visible.

Comment: @Justin984 Aren't they in another `ScrollViewer` though?

Comment: Bah, I was going to draw a little ascii pic, but it's too much of a pain. The listboxes each have multiple entries. For example, list box 1 may have 10 entries, which require scrolling the listbox in order to view. But there are multiple listboxes which, together, are too large for the screen, so i have an outer scrollviewer to scroll the listboxes into view. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Justin984 Perhaps you can do something where if the ListView is already scrolled to the bottom, it stops responding to scroll down events? Or instead passes them to the outer `ScrollViewer`?

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12080370/316760) [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4342746/316760) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23346121/316760), I have an implementation that scrolls ancestor ScrollViewers when inner ones (including from ListView, ListBox, DataGrid) scroll past their top/bottom.

I apply an attached property to all ScrollViewers in App.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollViewer" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ScrollViewer}}">
    <Setter Property="local:ScrollViewerHelper.FixMouseWheel" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

The attached property detects scrolling past top/bottom, and when that happens raises a mouse wheel event on the ScrollViewer's parent. Event routing gets it to the outer ScrollViewer:

```cs
public static class ScrollViewerHelper
{
    // Attached property boilerplate
    public static bool GetFixMouseWheel(ScrollViewer scrollViewer) => (bool)scrollViewer?.GetValue(FixMouseWheelProperty);
    public static void SetFixMouseWheel(ScrollViewer scrollViewer, bool value) => scrollViewer?.SetValue(FixMouseWheelProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FixMouseWheelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FixMouseWheel", typeof(bool), typeof(ScrollViewerHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnFixMouseWheelChanged));
    // End attached property boilerplate

    static void OnFixMouseWheelChanged(DependencyObject d,
                                       DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollViewer = d as ScrollViewer;
        if (scrollViewer == null) return;

        scrollViewer.PreviewMouseWheel += (s2, e2) =>
        {
            var parent = scrollViewer.Parent as UIElement;
            bool hitTopOrBottom = HitTopOrBottom(e2.Delta, scrollViewer);
            if (parent is null || !hitTopOrBottom) return;

            var argsCopy = Copy(e2);
            parent.RaiseEvent(argsCopy);
        };
    }

    static bool HitTopOrBottom(double delta, ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
    {
        var contentVerticalOffset = scrollViewer.ContentVerticalOffset;

        var atTop = contentVerticalOffset == 0;
        var movedUp = delta > 0;
        var hitTop = atTop && movedUp;

        var atBottom =
            contentVerticalOffset == scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;
        var movedDown = delta < 0;
        var hitBottom = atBottom && movedDown;

        return hitTop || hitBottom;
    }

    static MouseWheelEventArgs Copy(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        => new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta)
        {
            RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent,
            Source = e.Source,
        };
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, except I had to use TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}" instead of TargetType="ScrollViewer"

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the inner listview in a scrollviewer then the scrolling will work.

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListView>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Kos I created this custom WPF UiComponent:

```
namespace ListViewUnscrollable_UiComponent_WPF;

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public class ListViewUnscrollable : ListView
{
    public ListViewUnscrollable()
    {
        // Create a new ControlTemplate
        ControlTemplate template = new ControlTemplate(typeof(ListView));

        // Create and set the template's visual tree
        FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ItemsPresenter));
        template.VisualTree = factory;

        // Apply the template
        this.Template = template;
    }
}
```

I recommend putting it in a WPF components class library. To use it you need to import the namespace in your UserControl/Window:

```
xmlns:listViewUnscrollable="clr-namespace:ListViewUnscrollable_UiComponent_WPF;assembly=ListViewUnscrollable_UiComponent_WPF"
```

And replace your ListView with the wrapped one:

```
<listViewUnscrollable:ListViewUnscrollable><Label>Touch scroll works here!</Label></listViewUnscrollable:ListViewUnscrollable>
```

Don't forget to reference your library.

Generally I found it hard to believe that this is still a problem in 2024...