# Child elements of scrollviewer preventing scrolling with mouse wheel?

Tags: wpf, event-handling, listbox, scrollviewer, mousewheel

I'm having a problem getting mouse wheel scrolling to work in the following XAML, which I have simplified for clarity:

```
<ScrollViewer
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
CanContentScroll="False"
>
    <Grid
    MouseDown="Editor_MouseDown"
    MouseUp="Editor_MouseUp"
    MouseMove="Editor_MouseMove"
    Focusable="False"
    >
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type local:DataFieldModel}"
            >
                <Grid
                Margin="0,2,2,2"
                >
                    <TextBox
                    Cursor="IBeam"
                    MouseDown="TextBox_MouseDown"
                    MouseUp="TextBox_MouseUp"
                    MouseMove="TextBox_MouseMove"
                    />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ListBox
        x:Name="DataFieldListBox"
        ItemsSource="{Binding GetDataFields}"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        Background="Transparent"
        Focusable="False"
        >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style
                TargetType="ListBoxItem"
                >
                    <Setter
                    Property="Canvas.Left"
                    Value="{Binding dfX}"
                    />
                    <Setter
                    Property="Canvas.Top"
                    Value="{Binding dfY}"
                    />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Visually, the result is an area of some known size where `DataField`s read from a collection can be represented with `TextBox`es which have arbitrary position, size, et cetera.  In cases where the `ListBox`'s styled "area" is too large to display all at once, horizontal and vertical scrolling is possible, but only with the scroll bars.

For better ergonomics and sanity, mouse wheel scrolling should be possible, and normally `ScrollViewer` would handle it automatically, but the `ListBox` appears to be handing those events such that the parent `ScrollViewer` never sees them.  So far I have only been able to get wheel scrolling working be setting `IsHitTestVisible=False` for either the `ListBox` or the parent `Grid`, but of course none of the child element's mouse events work after that.

What can I do to ensure the `ScrollViewer` sees mouse wheel events while preserving others for child elements?

Edit: I just learned that `ListBox` has a built-in `ScrollViewer` which is probably stealing wheel events from the parent `ScrollViewer` and that specifying a control template can disable it.  I'll update this question if that resolves the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Specifying a `ControlTemplate` for the `Listbox` which doesn't include a `ScrollViewer` solves the problem.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1739298/1457236) and these two MSDN pages for more information:

[ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate(v=vs.100).aspx)

[ListBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: This also works for `TreeView`instead of the `ListBox`. Thanks!

Answer (score 65):

You can also create a behavior and attach it to the parent control (in which the scroll events should bubble through).

```
// Used on sub-controls of an expander to bubble the mouse wheel scroll event up 
public sealed class BubbleScrollEvent : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel += AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel -= AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    void AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        var e2 = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
        e2.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;
        AssociatedObject.RaiseEvent(e2);
    }
}

<SomePanel>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <viewsCommon:BubbleScrollEvent />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</SomePanel>
```

Comment: It works !!! Thank you very much (do not forget to add the namespace xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity")

Comment: Just a note to anyone else trying to use this solution.  You will need to install the Expression Blend SDK in order to get access to `System.Windows.Interactivity`.  The NuGet command `Install-Package Expression.Blend.Sdk` will install it for you.

Comment: @JoeB This is the better answer by far. Works easily with themes and other styles/templates!

Comment: @BradleyUffner FYI, worked for me on VS2013 Ultimate without the Expression Blend SDK. Interestingly, ReSharper added the namespace `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"` though, so not sure if it's just included now.

Comment: +1 It works, but I don't understand why it works :( In all my WPF experience setting `e.Handled = true` is enough, but in this occasion I have to raise the event again!? Anyway, thanks for a workaround!

Comment: A note for the future readers. I was trying to implement this in a `ListBox` where my `ListBoxItem`s were stealing wheel event. This solution didn't work for me initially until I realized that I needed to attach this behavior to the items, not the parent ListBox. Maybe it will help someone down the road.

Comment: Seriously, this is the only answer that worked properly for me. Works perfectly with our MVVM solution.

Comment: I got design-time error `XamlObjectWriterException: Collection property 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel'.'Behaviors' is null.` within parent UserControl

Comment: Is it working with panning events using a touchscreen ?

Answer (score 5):

Another way of implementing this, is by creating you own ScrollViewer like this:

```
public class MyScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
{
    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        var parentElement = Parent as UIElement;
        if (parentElement != null)
        {
            if ((e.Delta > 0 && VerticalOffset == 0) ||
                (e.Delta < 0 && VerticalOffset == ScrollableHeight))
            {
                e.Handled = true;

                var routedArgs = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
                routedArgs.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;
                parentElement.RaiseEvent(routedArgs);
            }
        }

        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little late but I have another solution that worked for me. I switched out my stackpanel/listbox for an itemscontrol/grid. Not sure why the scroll events work properly but they do in my case.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DrillingConfigs}" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
```

became

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DrillingConfigs}" Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This is because <ItemsControl> is more "dumb" control (actually, it's the ancestor for ListBox) and it's have no support for scrolling at all. So you got a solution that _potentially_ is slower than previous version (ListBox-based).

Answer (score 0):

isHitTestVisible=False in the child works great for me

Edit This isnt a good way to do it

Comment: This effectively disables scrolling (and any other interaction) in the nested scroll viewer though.

Comment: Yes I realised this a bit late! I will edit my response. Thank you