# How to prevent ListView from stealing scroll activity on Datagrid parent?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, scroll, datagrid

I have a ListView within a DataGridTemplateColumn, if the mouse cursor is over an item within the ListView and the user attempts to scroll the DataGrid, the DataGrid doesn't scroll.

I have tried the following but it still occurs:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...
```

Edit: Providing example below of where this is used, I'm using ListView to make the items wrap on overflow.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="120" ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}" ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Hyperlink TextDecorations="{x:Null}" NavigateUri="{Binding Path=.}" RequestNavigate="Name_RequestNavigate">
                                <TextBlock Padding="1" Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource NameToLocale}}"/>
                            </Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ways:

**A)** Change list view `ControlTemplate` to remove `ScrollViewer` from it:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ItemsPresenter/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListView.Template>
    ...
</ListView>
```

---

**B)** Another way is create a behavior for parent element base on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348517/child-elements-of-scrollviewer-preventing-scrolling-with-mouse-wheel#16110178)

```
// Used on sub-controls of an expander to bubble the mouse wheel scroll event up 
public sealed class BubbleScrollEvent : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel += AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel -= AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    void AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        var e2 = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
        e2.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;
        AssociatedObject.RaiseEvent(e2);
    }
}

<SomePanel>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <viewsCommon:BubbleScrollEvent />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</SomePanel>
```