# Disable scrolling in ScrollViewer child of a Frame which has a ScrollViewer as parent

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, frame, scrollviewer

#### State

I have a `Page` (`Page_Child`) with a `ScrollViewer` (`ScrollViewer_Child`) in a `Frame` (`Frame_Parent`) which is the child of my parent `ScrollViewer` (`ScrollViewer_Parent`).

```
<ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewer_Parent">
    <StackPanel>
        <Frame Name="Frame_Parent">
            <Frame.Content>

                <Page Name="Page_Child">
                    <ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewer_Child">
                        <!-- Page Content -->
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Page>

            </Frame.Content>
        </Frame>
        <!-- ... -->
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

#### Problem

What I try to achieve is to disable the `ScrollViewer` in the `Frame` as the parent `ScrollViewer` can handle all of the seizing thanks to the not fixed height of the `Frame`. - Or at least let the parent continue scrolling when the child reached the top or the bottom.

*Sadly I can't use any external resources or libraries, nor can I remove the child `ScrollViewer` as it's visualized somewhere else in my application.*

#### Question

Is there a way of telling the frame content to disable scrolling or how to archive the continues scrolling through the frame?

Comment: What about using a behaviour so if the frame receives a mousewheel event it will bubble it up to the scroll viewer. I've used the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16110178/5084488 before and it works really well

Comment: @Alfie cannot use any DLL's or external resources for my application (only able to use the standard windows libraries and .NET 4.0) :/

Comment: oh okay, you could try do the same thing but just in code behind by attaching void `Frame_Parent_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e) {  e.Handled = true; ScrollViewer_Parent.RaiseEvent(e); }` to the PreviewMouseWheel event of Frame_Parent? Or have I misinterpreted you?

Comment: I misunderstood you, your solution is perfect, though I need this interactive stuff - would you like to write an answer so I can give you the accepted answer badge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were able to use external libraries you could use the behaviour here: [BubbleScrollEvent Behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16110178/5084488), but as you cannot you can simply just write a similar thing but in the code behind;

by attaching a method to the `PreviewMouseWheel` event of `Frame` which will route the event to the `ScrollViewer` like so:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewer_Parent">
    <StackPanel PreviewMouseWheel="BubblePreviewMouseWheel">
        <Frame Name="Frame_Parent" PreviewMouseWheel="BubblePreviewMouseWheel" />
            ...
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>


private void BubblePreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    var e2 = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
    e2.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;
    ((UIElement)sender).RaiseEvent(e2);
}
```

---

*Edit: Just realised it would raise the event to the `StackPanel` so you would need to attach `BubblePreviewMouseWheel` to the `StackPanel` as well.*